# Secure WSDL for Metro Style Apps

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, windows-8

I have some web services that I need to reference in a Windows 8 Metro style application, normally you can just add a reference to the service via VS2012, but the services are behind a security layer.

I have downloaded the .WSDL file to my local PC, and now I need to generate the class file for this service.

The WSDL.exe that I have found on my local PC is for .NET 4.0 and produces code that is not suitable for the .NETCore framework. Is there a WSDL.exe equivalent for Windows 8 apps?

Visual Studio 2012 can obviously add a reference to non-secure asmx WSDL web services, so the functionality must be somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this if anyone is interested.

You simply download the XML WSDL file from the site via a normal browser.

Then in VS2012, you can add a service reference to that file directly (i.e. put in the full path to the file c:\tmp\mywsdl.xml) and it will be able to generate the proxy for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per little investigation, the original .NET 1.x asmx-based Web Reference proxies are not supported in Metro style apps.

Web Service with SOAP 1.1 end point is supported by Add Service Reference (right-click on a project and choose Add Service Reference) in Metro style apps.

A workaround should be remove the offending constructor that fails to build (unfortunately, you'll need to do that everytime you regenerate the code), and to pass an instance BasicHttpBinding and EndpointAddress to one of the constructors of the WSFTerminalsSoapClient.

Have a look at following references, which might help you in this regard:

[Web Services from WinRT Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470543/web-services-from-winrt-metro)

[WCF in Windows 8 Metro styled apps? Absolutely supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx)

Comment: I cant add a service reference because the WSDL is protected... I tried a normal public WSDL, which worked fine, just not secure ones